# Am I using file.seek and file.tell correctly?

Tags: python

first time asking a question here, but pretty stumped and could do with a hand.

So i'm writing a program in python for a project involving argumentation. This script overall needs to take some nodes from a json file, and decide upon the linear order of the argument, and the put it correctly into a tree in order. However, the main issue I am having here is very basic. I need to move the line reader back one line if the "nodeInt" equals the "nodeIdentifier", so I can read a value from a previous line (the fromID). I've highlighted where these are used (one "seek", two "tell")

Unfortunately, currently it's just reading the same line and does not seem to be moving back like I believe it should. Have I just used these commands incorrectly or is something else wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
while addingToList == False:
    if "toID" in line:
        print "finding id"
        print line
        #Finding the ID
        idStart = line.index(":")
        nodeID = line[idStart+1:idStart+3]
        nodeInt = int(nodeID)
        if nodeInt == nodeIdentifier:
            print "matching id"
            **input.seek(last_pos)**
            line = input.readline()
            print line
            fromStart = line.index(":")
            fromID = line[fromStart+1:fromStart+3]
            fromInt = int(fromID)
            print "FromID"
            print fromInt
            line = input.readline()
            line = input.readline()
        else:
            **last_pos = input.tell()**
            line = input.readline()
    elif "schemefulfillments" in line:
        print "reached end"
        addingToList = True    

    else:
        **last_pos = input.tell()**
        line = input.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not sure if you've just not included it or if it actually isn't there, but you're missing the declaration for `last_pos` before you use it as the `seek` index.
Check out [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) on using `seek` and `tell` as well; it should be pretty helpful here.

Comment: Yeah it's not used until the else, as the else always comes before the "if" statement. I'll have a look though, thanks